# drawInRect:withAttributes dies with "message sent to deallocated instance"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I am updating an app for iOS 7. One of the changes is switching to the new drawInRect:withAttributes function instead of the deprecated drawInRect:withFont...
This was working fine on the iOS 7 beta, but today after upgrading to the latest iOS 7 version, the app crashes on the line:

```
[text drawInRect:theRect withAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSz], NSFontAttributeName, color, NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil]];
```

With the message:

```
*** -[NSStringDrawingTextStorage textContainerForAttributedString:containerSize:lineFragmentPadding:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x187ed0f0
```

I tried running the Zombie instrument, which is not helpful at all neither the allocation nor the release of the object in question are in my code. Specifically I get the message:

```
An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated 'NSStringDrawingTextStorage' object (zombie) at address: 0x169edc50.
```

And the malloc/release of the object are under the caller:

```
[NSStringDrawingTextStorage stringDrawingTextStorage]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around this by trimming the leading whitespace (including newline characters) from the NSString I was rendering. Here's my category method:

```
- (NSString*)stringByTrimmingLeadingWhitespace
{
    NSUInteger index = 0;

    while((index < [self length]) && [[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet] characterIsMember: [self characterAtIndex: index]])
    {
        index++;
    }

    return [self substringFromIndex: index];
}
```

Unfortunately if you must preserve the leading newline character(s), I do not have an alternative answer.

Comment: thanks a lot! I was setting the text of a UILabel with a text which started with \n on a separated thread, so my crash was completely unrelated to what the debugger showed, but your solution pointed me in the right direction.

by the way, you can more easily trim NSString with:

[sMyString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];