# NSStringDrawingTextStorage textContainerForAttributedString:containerSize:lineFragmentPadding

Tags: nsstring, ios7, nsattributedstring, drawinrect

Instance method of String to get height of text `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` is deprecated for ios7. So I used `boundingRectWithSize:options:context:`. 
But it shows this issue:

> -[NSStringDrawingTextStorage textContainerForAttributedString:containerSize:lineFragmentPadding:]: message sent to deallocated instance

My text is like this :

`\n Hello Test String \n\n Again Test String \n Test String`

I dont know the issue but I think may be the \n characters or other HTML characters are the reason for this.
I tried this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938729/drawinrectwithattributes-dies-with-message-sent-to-deallocated-instance). But not any help.

Please guide what to do...!!!

Thanks in advance.