# determining what originated a crash in my code

Tags: ios, crash

I'm getting crashes in a user's device (I see it in Crashalytics)
The thing is that the core dump is all iOS internal stuff.
How can I see what peice of my code originated the draw that made the crash?

```
Terminating app due to an uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSAttributeDictionary textContainerForAttributedString:containerSize:lineFragmentPadding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15dc7f20'
0   CoreFoundation  0x30065f23  +154
1   libobjc.A.dylib 0x3a7fcce7  objc_exception_throw+38
2   CoreFoundation  0x30069837  +202
3   CoreFoundation  0x30068137  +706
4   CoreFoundation  0x2ffb7098  _CF_forwarding_prep_0+24
5   UIFoundation    0x37ce5915  +12252
6   UIFoundation    0x37ce2863  +150
7   UIKit   0x328ae2c9  +4224
8   UIKit   0x32914709  +500
9   UIKit   0x3291450b  +78
10  UIKit   0x329144a9  +372
11  QuartzCore  0x32540189  +100
12  QuartzCore  0x32529c5b  +1858
13  QuartzCore  0x32605c1d  +52
14  QuartzCore  0x3252950b  +82
15  QuartzCore  0x325291bf  +1118
16  QuartzCore  0x3250cd41  +208
17  QuartzCore  0x3250c9d9  +24
18  QuartzCore  0x3250c3e5  +228
19  QuartzCore  0x3250c1f7  +314
20  QuartzCore  0x325398e3  +162
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3ae176d1  +164
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3ae17453  +86
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3ae181b9  pthread_exit+28
24  Foundation  0x309a2703  +10
25  Foundation  0x30a4ea2d  +1092
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3ae18959  +140
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3ae188cb  _pthread_start+102
```

**** Edit ****
A different thread that crashed in this run (which again gives me no hints to the original point in my code)

```
Thread : Crashed: Thread
0  libsystem_c.dylib              0x3ad6206a __abort + 101
1  libsystem_c.dylib              0x3ad6206b __abort + 102
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x3ad62005 __abort
3  libc++abi.dylib                0x3a1b098f abort_message + 74
4  libc++abi.dylib                0x3a1c96e7 default_terminate_handler() + 254
5  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3a7fcf7d _objc_terminate() + 192
6  libc++abi.dylib                0x3a1c71b3 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 78
7  libc++abi.dylib                0x3a1c6a09 __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*)
8  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3a7fcdbb objc_exception_throw + 250
9  CoreFoundation                 0x30069837 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 202
10 CoreFoundation                 0x30068137 ___forwarding___ + 706
11 CoreFoundation                 0x2ffb7098 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
12 UIFoundation                   0x37ce5915 __NSStringDrawingEngine + 12252
13 UIFoundation                   0x37ce2863 -[NSString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) drawWithRect:options:attributes:context:] + 150
14 UIKit                          0x328ae2c9 -[UILabel _drawTextInRect:baselineCalculationOnly:] + 4224
15 UIKit                          0x32914709 -[UILabel drawTextInRect:] + 500
16 UIKit                          0x3291450b -[UILabel drawRect:] + 78
17 UIKit                          0x329144a9 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 372
18 QuartzCore                     0x32540189 -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 100
19 QuartzCore                     0x32529c5b CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 1858
20 QuartzCore                     0x32605c1d ___ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev_block_invoke + 52
21 QuartzCore                     0x3252950b x_blame_allocations + 82
22 QuartzCore                     0x325291bf CA::Layer::display_() + 1118
23 QuartzCore                     0x3250cd41 CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 208
24 QuartzCore                     0x3250c9d9 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 24
25 QuartzCore                     0x3250c3e5 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 228
26 QuartzCore                     0x3250c1f7 CA::Transaction::commit() + 314
27 QuartzCore                     0x325398e3 CA::Transaction::release_thread(void*) + 162
28 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3ae176d1 _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 164
29 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3ae17453 _pthread_exit + 86
30 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3ae181b9 pthread_exit + 28
31 Foundation                     0x309a2703 +[NSThread exit] + 10
32 Foundation                     0x30a4ea2d __NSThread__main__ + 1092
33 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3ae18959 _pthread_body + 140
34 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3ae188cb _pthread_start + 102
```

Comment: reason: '-[NSAttributeDictionary textContainerForAttributedString:containerSize:lineFragmentPadding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15dc7f20, for this reason u r getting exception.

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23949168/button-shape-on-in-device-iphone-setting-result-app-crash-if-its-off-app-worki

Comment: I saw that one... I was wondering if I can find out which button/label is causing it...

Comment: This looks like the thread where the exception happened and that will never show where the exception occured. Doesn't the report also show the `Last Exception Backtrace`? Please post as much of the crash report as possible.

Comment: @Kerni - added another thread that crashed. The rest of the threads seem to be irrelevant

Comment: Note that crashes during drawing will hardly ever give you a clear pointer to the parameter that you (inevitably) set wrong or failed to retain or whatever in your code.  A goodly amount of intuition is required.  (Have you run Analyzer?)

Comment: The service you are using allows to share a full crash report. Could you please activate that and add a lnk to it. We need to see the full report.

Comment: @Kerni - do you mean http://crashes.to/s/a5c765c6fd3?

Answer (score 0):

What's unusual is that you are only getting this crash in production and not in development.  That's probably due to poor testing, however another possible reason is making assumptions about the type of data you are working with, and this data is difficult to replicate in development.

JSON is a common and classic example of this, where a server can provide a string response that is magically turned into a hierarchy of objects.  The code then assumes the top-level objects is a dictionary or array and starts calling methods which are unrecognised.

In your case though, you are not testing properly before release.

(this doesn't really provide an answer, but I feel you have everything you need to provide yourself with the answer, if you can be bothered to use it).

Comment: You are right in a general way, and I probably do have a bug in my code, but since this crash happens for a single user out of hundreds of users, And trying to simulate his actions on a test version didn't recreate the problem - I wanted some help to see if I can isolate the problem in MY code. Lectures are nice, but StackOverflow should be a safe environment to get assitance

Comment: A crash in production and not in testing is often due having been compiled for production/optimized vs debug mode.  One should always test a version compiled for production.